# Backbone.View.$el.html() has no effect on the DOM

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views

Having understood how Backbone.js communicates with the server, I'm now having trouble with Backbone.View.render().

My javascript code is this:

```
var myObject = Backbone.Model.extend( {
    fetch: function (options) {
      // some modifications
    }
});

var Templates = myObject.extend({
    urlRoot: 'templates/load.php',
    initialize: function() {
        this.fetch();
    }
});

var appTemplates = new Templates();
```

load.php loads all template files and transforms them to one JSON object that is then returned to the client. So `appTemplates` will have all my Mustache.js templates ready for the page.

To test that, I created a 'main' template and a View:

```
var Output = Backbone.View.extend({

    template: function() {

        return appTemplates.get('main');
    },

    render: function() {

        var rendered = Mustache.to_html(this.template(), this.model.toJSON() );

        console.log( rendered ); // has exactly the data I want.

        this.$el.html( rendered ); // <body> ... </body> remains empty
        $('body').html( rendered ); // works fine.
        return this;
    },
});

var skeleton = new Output({ el: 'body', model: SomeModelData });

skeleton.listenTo(appTemplates, 'change', skeleton.render);
```

So why doesn't `this.$el.html()` work? I thought, `this.$el` is just a shortcut for `$(this.el)` but `this.el` is undefined, regarding the output of `console.log` (I did not define it? Thought I did...) while `this.model` works just fine.

The initial HTML is not very spectacular:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="./javascript/jquery-2.1.4.js" ></script>
    <script src="./javascript/underscore.js"></script>
    <script src="./javascript/backbone.js" ></script>
    <script src="./javascript/mustache.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./javascript/js.js"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

There is another issue with the `'main'` string in in the View constructor. If I send 'main' as a value to the constructor ( `{ tpl: 'main', ... }` ) `tpl` remains undefined.

What am I doing wrong here?

#### Edit: Problem solved

As it seems, the problem was that my js-file was included within the `<head>...</head>` of the html but it needs to be included within `<body>...</body>` to work as expected. If someone knows a reason for this I would love to hear about it.

Comment: Pretty strange. Try `.setElement('body')` and see if it does the trick.
http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-160

Comment: I don't see where you're calling `skeleton.render()`, you're binding it to an event but does that event get triggered?

Comment: @muistooshort When initializing appTemplates data is loaded from the server (needs some time). Until then the skeleton-listener is defined. When the data is loaded, the change event is triggered and skeleton.render() is executed.

Comment: @misantronic: That doesn't do the trick either. :( `this.el` remains undefined.

Comment: Your "Problem solved" suggests that there was no `<body>` when your JavaScript went looking for it. A more common solution is to wrap your start up code in `$(function() { /* create your first view here... */ })`.

Comment: *"load.php loads all template files and transforms them to one JSON object that is then returned to the client"* - when & how does this happen..?

Comment: *"this.el is undefined"* - where & how did you verify this..? `this` should be pointing to entirely different object when you tried to access `el`.

Comment: _»when & how does this happen..?«_ - `new Templates()` calls `Templates.initialize()` which calls the `fetch()`-Method that sends a request to the server. This happens at the beginning of the script.

Comment: _»where & how did you verify this..?«_ - I verified it inside the `Output.render()` method.